# Fetching and rendering a component in a loop

Tags: reactjs, string, components, render

I have a string array that contains usernames. I want to fetch those users in a loop, put them in an array and render a component for each user. I can retrieve the data from API and print it on console but the code below gives me a white screen.

Here I'm trying to fetch data one by one using fav_list array than contains usernames. Then I want to send the data to another component called InfluencerFavoritesCard and render them. Where I'm doing wrong?

```
import React from 'react'
import InfluencerFavoritesCard from '../components/influencerFavoritesCard/InfluencerFavoritesCard';

import "./indexPages.css"
import "./favorites.css"

const fav_list = ["cagritaner", "acunilicali", "neslihanatagul"]; 

async function ListFavorites() {

  let array = new Array;
  var fetches = [];

  for (let i = 0; i < fav_list.length; i++) {
    console.log(fav_list[i]);

    let uname = fav_list[i];

    fetches.push(
      fetch(`http://localhost:3001/api/users/${uname}`)
      .then(res => {return res.text(); })
        .then(res => {
            array.push(res);
            console.log(res);
          }
      )
    );
  }

  
  Promise.all(fetches).then(function () {
    console.log(fetches);
    console.log(array[0]);
    console.log(array.length);
  });

  return (
    <div>
      {array.map(item => (< InfluencerFavoritesCard  infCard = { item } /> ))}
    </div>
  );

}


function Favorites() {
  return (
    
    <div className='favoritesMain'>

      <div className='favoritesTitle-div'>
        <h3 className="favoritesTitle">FAVORİLER</h3>
      </div>

      <div className='favoritesContainer-wrapper'>
        <div className='favoritesContainer'>

          {<ListFavorites/>}

        </div>  
      </div>

      <div className='favoritesFooter'></div>
      
    </div> 

  );
}

export default Favorites
```

InfluencerFavoritesCard.jsx

```
import React from 'react';
import './influencerFavoritesCard.css';
    
const InfluencerFavoritesCard = ({ infCard }) => {
  return (
    <div className='infCard'>


      <div className='infCard-text-info' >
        <div className='infCard-name'>
          <h3>{infCard.name}</h3>
        </div>
        <div className='infCard-username'>
          <h4>{infCard.username}</h4>
        </div>
        <div className='infCard-categories'>
          <h4>{infCard.categories}</h4>
        </div>
      </div>


    </div>
  )
}

export default InfluencerFavoritesCard;
```

================================

UPDATED:

I have updated the parent component like below.

```
export function Favorites() {

  const [users, setUsers] = useState([]);
  const fav_list = ["cagritaner", "acunilicali", "neslihanatagul"];
  
  useEffect(() => {
    const tempUsersCollection = [];

    fav_list.map((x, i) => {
      fetch(`http://localhost:3001/api/users/${x}`)
      .then(res => {return res.json(); })
        .then(res => {
          tempUsersCollection.push(res.data.tour);
          console.log(res);
          }
      );
    });
    
    console.log(tempUsersCollection);
    setUsers(tempUsersCollection);
  }, []);

 
  return (
    
    <div className='favoritesMain'>

      <div className='favoritesTitle-div'>
        <h3 className="favoritesTitle">FAVORİLER</h3>
      </div>

      <div className='favoritesContainer-wrapper'>
        <div className='favoritesContainer'>
        {users.map((item, index) => (
            <InfluencerFavoritesCard
              infCard={item}
              key={`influencer-${item.username}-${index}`}
            />
          ))}
        </div>  
      </div>

      <div className='favoritesFooter'></div>
      
    </div> 

  );
}
```

output of the console.log(tempUsersCollection) (AFTER res.json() !! )

```
Array []
​
0: Object { username: "neslihanatagul", biography: "contact@neslihanatagul.com", profile_picture_url: "https://scontent.fist4-1.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t51.2885-15/5787050…0_AfDfN8wtsD18vya_aLLw6M4UpP8Xx16jb9b4Hsh6cJ3wjA&oe=63A713AF", … }
​
1: Object { username: "cagritaner", biography: "Hüzünlü Bir Ponçik ve Erkeklerin İç Sesi kitaplarının yazarı.\niş birlikleri  için; @goygoynetworkinfo", profile_picture_url: "https://scontent.fist4-1.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t51.2885-15/4424442…0_AfCXmyBbUrKQjpzsGEHNEMHXoNP7HZ8UKaYXHAL4S0DFlA&oe=63A6926B", … }
​
2: Object { username: "acunilicali", biography: "Acun Ilıcalı Resmi Instagram Hesabıdır.", profile_picture_url: "https://scontent.fist4-1.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t51.2885-15/1193932…0_AfDuL0toVKsSGOrnXWISBMAR78G79QwNfxJmm5cNFBuW2A&oe=63A78969", … }
​
length: 3
​
<prototype>: Array []
Favorites.jsx:136
```

Comment: array.push(res); is not pushing inside a state variable. Then the component don't know it should rerender. You should use setState for each of the changes that you would like to be shown on the screen immediate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thing is that `return` statement is being rendered before all the promises are resolved, meaning that it's empty. This is exactly how it should work, so no bug here.

What you need to do is as other mentioned, use `useState` and `useEffect` to control the data:

```js
// This will hold your collection 
const [users, setUsers] = useState([])
...
// And here you need to update that collection
useEffect(()=>{
const temp = []
fetch(`http://localhost:3001/api/users/${uname}`)
  .then(res => {return res.text(); })
    .then(res => {
     temp.push(res);
    }
)
setUsers(temp)
}, [])
```

Later on the `return` you can do this:

```js
// This controls if there are no users
if(users.length <= 0){
 return <>There are no users</>
}

return (
<div className='favoritesMain'>
 <div className='favoritesTitle-div'>
  <h3 className="favoritesTitle">FAVORİLER</h3>
 </div>

 <div className='favoritesContainer-wrapper'>
  <div className='favoritesContainer'>
   {users.map(item => (<InfluencerFavoritesCard  infCard = { item } /> ))}
    </div>
 </div>

 <div className='favoritesFooter'></div>
</div> 
);
```

Created a [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/suspicious-worker-v01nu7?file=/src/App.js) so you can see this working

---

UPDATE:

```js
// Call the function after the first render
 useEffect(() => {
    fetchUsers();
  }, []);

// Wrapped all the calls in a Promise.all and update the state
  async function fetchUsers() {
    const response = await Promise.all(
      fav_list.map((x) =>
        fetch(`https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/${x}`)
          .then((res) => res.json())
          .then((user) => user)
      )
    );
    console.log(response);

    setUsers(response);
  }

// Handle the case where nothing is retrieved
  if (users.length <= 0) {
    return <>There are no users</>;
  }
```

Comment: Should I put the first part of your answer in InfluencerFavoritesCard.jsx ?

Comment: hey @questionhead I've added a link to a CodeSandbox, so you can check how it should be organized.
https://codesandbox.io/s/suspicious-worker-v01nu7?file=/src/App.js

Comment: No. The first part (useState and useEffect) should be added to the parent component; once you've retrieved the data, you can pass it to your `InfluencerFavoritesCard` component.

Comment: A couple more tips: 1. Try to avoid using `default` exports, as they are cumbersome to handle and it's easier to export just the function. 2. Do not forget the `keys` while iterating on a `map` they are the way to identify changes on the DOM, and can cause performance issues, if they are not good formed (like really unique)

Comment: I appreciate your effort, but it seems like the parent component is still rendering before the InfluencerFavoritesCard.

Comment: Well, of course. The hierarchy on React goes from parent to child. In this case, your parent (`Favorites`) has the loop and retrieves the data, then in the render, it passes the data to the child (`InfluencerFavoritesCard`).

Comment: From the update you did, what's the output of `console.log(res);` in the second `then`. Do you really need 2 `then`? you can handle both actions (JSON.parse() and push) in the same `then`

Comment: When I said the parent component is still rendering before the child, misleaded you, my bad. I wanted to say child components are still not rendering.

Comment: console.log(res) output is correct. I will fix double res, but I need to be able to render child InfluencerProfileCard component first.

Comment: OK, the problem is in the fetch. If the state variable `users` is empty (`[]`) there shouldn't render anything in the `InfluencerProfileCard`, right? can you mock your fetch response? with that you'll see  that the render is working. If you check my CodeSandbox, I added some more code in line 28, if you place that in your component you'll see that the `users` is not being populated from the fetch

Comment: @questionhead I think I fixed it in the CodeSandbox. I think the problem was the `fetch` is `async` by default, so your `tempCollection` was empty when we set the `setUsers` , but the results were right slightly later. What I did was, move the fetch inside it's own async function. Also wrapped it inside an `await Promise.all()`, so the code will wait for all the promises to resolve. Then it updates  the state. Please give it a try.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/250877/discussion-between-thremulant-and-questionhead).

Comment: You saved my day, thank you so much from the bottom of my heart.

Answer (score 1):

To fetch data asynchronously, you need to use the `useEffect` hook. You should store the data using a `useState` hook and then set that data when you get a response from your fetch request.